# How can I get the values from CKEDITOR using POST in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I have a trouble in getting the value of CKEDITOR in HTML.
After inputting some HTML tags in the CKEDITOR and submitting it. There's no output from the POST response. Here's my code. I don't know if it some complication because i also used jquery-validation plugin.

**HTML**

```
<?php echo form_open('users/user/sendEmail', array('id' => 'send-mail-form', 'role' => 'form')); ?>
<div class="row row_field">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="editor">Email Body:</label>
        <textarea name="email_body" id="editor"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#editor').ckeditor();
```

**jquery-validation**

```
$('#send-mail-form').validate({
    rules: {
        email_subject: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 15
        },
        email_body: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 50
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email_subject: {
            required: "The Email Subject is required",
            minlength: "The email subject shoud be 15 characters and above."
        },
        email_body: {
            required: "Email body is required",
            minlength: "The email body should be 5o characters and above."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit(); //send data
    }
});
```

**PHP server side**

```
public function sendEmail() {

        fp($this->input->post()); //no output 

        fp(htmlentities($this->input->post('email_body'))); //no output also
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();

    // Your code to save "data", usually through Ajax.
</script>
```

Or

```
<?php
    $editor_data = $_POST[ 'editor1' ];   // where editor1 is the name of html element
?>
```

[Reference Guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata)

Comment: So I need to do it via AJAX? :Ok ill try

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys,
I manage to solve it by downloading this small plugin
http://ckeditor.com/addon/save

And I add the configuration in my js part.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'save';
```

And now I can get the CKEDITOR value.

Comment: Hi sir, can you check my post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206753/how-to-et-the-value-in-the-ckeditor-codeigniter

Comment: Page not found 404

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this method

```
$details =  htmlentities($_POST['editor']);
```

Comment: `$_POST['editor']` will not exist as `editor` is the ID of the textarea - POST uses the name

Comment: ooh yes. sorry for the mistake  , need to use "email_body"

Answer (score 0):

Just try this and it works fine

```
 $("form[name='blog_form']").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();  // editor is the textarea field's name
    $("form[name='blog_form'] textarea[name='editor']").val(editor_data);
    var data = new FormData(this);
```

You will get all the form's fields & their values and confirm with the network in the google console.
like:

```
b_title: This is just a testing Title of the blog.
b_heading: This is the Heading of the Blog.
b_date: 2019-09-06
b_time: 17:00
b_excerpt: test
editor: <p>testing <strong>may be fine </strong>now with&nbsp; the <span 
style="color:#1abc9c"><span style="font-size:24px">TextEditor</span></span></p>
b_file: (binary)
b_tags: tags
```

we are now getting our texteditor value in the editor-key above.

On the PHP page you can just get the values like:

```
$blog = new Blog($db);

$blog->b_title = $_POST['b_title'];
$blog->b_heading = $_POST['b_heading'];
$blog->b_content = $_POST['editor'];  // ... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Mayank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5921745/mayank-pandeyz) answer was right, but i've made a most flexible approach for this using "for in" syntax, you can make the following on your submitHandler, just before send the data:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    //Update textarea elements before send...
    for (let input in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[input].updateElement();
    }

    form.submit(); //send data
}
```

And you got the correctly data on $_POST